# Quaternions discontinuities

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

It is claimed in this paper: https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Zhou_On_the_Continuity_of_Rotation_Representations_in_Neural_Networks_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf (page 5748)

that the mapping from mapping from rotations to quaternions is discontinuous at 180 degrees.

It doesn't seem true.

Rotation of 3.1 radians around z-axis:

Matrix

[ -0.9991351, -0.0415807,  0.0000000;

0.0415807, -0.9991351,  0.0000000;

0.0000000,  0.0000000,  1.0000000 ]

Quaternion

[ 0, 0, 0.9997838, 0.0207948 ]

---

Rotation of 3.3 radians around z-axis:

[ -0.9874797,  0.1577457,  0.0000000;

-0.1577457, -0.9874797,  0.0000000;

0.0000000,  0.0000000,  1.0000000 ]

Quaternion:

[ 0, 0, 0.996865, -0.0791209 ]

As we can see, the quaternion representation barely changed. I would hardly call this discontinuous.

Comment: This is not a proof or disproof of continuity. Simply checking one case proves nothing.

Comment: Maybe they refer to "gimbal lock" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock

Comment: @MattSamuel We would expect to see the behavior at 180 degree. See the paper. thats exactly what they say

Comment: This is definitely gimble lock and it's the main motivation for using quaternions for rotational computations over traditional linear methods. This can have significant real-world consequences if you're say, designing a fly-by-wire system for aircraft. You don't want the plane suddenly flipping upside down.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD1043624.pdf

> When determining quaternions from a rotation matrix, there is a
> nonuniqueness as 2 sets of quaternions can be determined for any
> general rotation matrix. A common means of dealing with this problem
> is to ensure that one of the quaterion components is always positive.
> While this guarantees a unique solution acceptable for many
> applications, it forces a discontinuous sign change in other
> components.

In this case, if you always wanted to keep your 4th term positive, the quaternion for the rotation of 3.1 radians will be same which is

[ 0, 0, 0.9997838, 0.0207948 ]                (1)

However when you talk about 3.3 radians and talking about unique quaternioins, to get the 4th term positive you'll have to multiply the entire quaternion by -1, i.e

-[0, 0, 0.996865, -0.0791209]

Which is equal to  [0, 0, -0.99685, 0.079] (2)

Comparing quaternion (1) and quaternion (2) you can see a jump in the sign and hence the discontinuity at pi radians.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I know what you're getting at, but let me know if I get it wrong (assuming you're still invested in an explanation!).

I don't know which specific mapping the paper chose. It's possible they chose the mapping in which each rotation gets mapped to the appropriate quaternion with a positive scalar (real) component. In that case, the second quaternion would be $0.079121-0.996865\mathbf{k}$, which is (as advertised) far off from the corresponding quaternion at $3.1$ radians.

The underlying issue is that the quaternions are a double cover of $SO(3)$, and for the mapping from $SO(3)$ to $\mathbb{H}^*$, you have to choose which quaternion goes to each rotation. No matter what choices you make, you will end up with a neighborhood of rotations *somewhere* that has widely divergent quaternions.

---

A similar thing happens if you try to define a square root function on the complex plane. Here, again, you have two choices for $\sqrt{z}$ if $w^2 = z$: $w$ and $-w$. If you were to choose whichever one has positive real component (by analogy with what we just did with the quaternions), you end up with a discontinuity at $z = -1$, no matter whether you pick $i$ or $-i$.

Nor can you avoid the problem by making other choices. Imagine traversing the unit circle counterclockwise from $1$, back to $1$. Whatever choice you make for your square root, traverses the same circle in the same direction, but at half the speed. So suppose you choose $\sqrt{1} = 1$ (sensibly). Then you have

$$
\sqrt{i} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i
$$
$$
\sqrt{-1} = i
$$
$$
\sqrt{-i} = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i
$$

and lastly, $\sqrt{1} = -1$. Oops. We've made $z$ make a full turn around the origin, but its square root has only made a half turn.

Nor can you even fix this by making the square root multi-valued, because now you have to decide which value comes "first." The best you can say is that both values are valid square roots, but you can't make square root a continuous *function*.

---

Anyway, we can make the same problem happen in the quaternions by looking at the mapping of rotations of $\theta$ around the $z$-axis, all the way from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi$. Whatever you do, you either have a discontinuity somewhere along the way, or else you end up swapping $1$ for $-1$.